# JS code works when i paste it on console, but does not work inside my React App

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, payment-gateway

Okay so, there is that code:

```js
var iyziInit = {
  currency: "TRY",
  token: "23bfa27a-172a-493d-b42f-8b091589eaa0",
  price: 2.4,
  locale: "tr",
  baseUrl: "https://sandbox-api.iyzipay.com",
  merchantGatewayBaseUrl: "https://sandbox-merchantgw.iyzipay.com",
  registerCardEnabled: true,
  bkmEnabled: true,
  bankTransferEnabled: false,
  bankTransferRedirectUrl: "https://localhost:3000/callback",
  bankTransferCustomUIProps: {},
  campaignEnabled: false,
  creditCardEnabled: true,
  bankTransferAccounts: [],
  userCards: [],
  fundEnabled: true,
  memberCheckoutOtpData: {},
  force3Ds: false,
  isSandbox: true,
  storeNewCardEnabled: true,
  paymentWithNewCardEnabled: true,
  enabledApmTypes: ["SOFORT", "IDEAL", "QIWI", "GIROPAY"],
  payWithIyzicoUsed: false,
  payWithIyzicoEnabled: true,
  payWithIyzicoCustomUI: {},
  buyerName: "John",
  buyerSurname: "Doe",
  merchantInfo: "",
  cancelUrl: "",
  buyerProtectionEnabled: false,
  hide3DS: false,
  gsmNumber: "",
  email: "email@email.com",
  checkConsumerDetail: {},
  subscriptionPaymentEnabled: false,
  ucsEnabled: false,
  fingerprintEnabled: false,
  payWithIyzicoFirstTab: false,
  metadata: {},
  createTag: function() {
    var iyziJSTag = document.createElement("script");
    iyziJSTag.setAttribute(
      "src",
      "https://sandbox-static.iyzipay.com/checkoutform/v2/bundle.js?v=1634688058781"
    );
    document.head.appendChild(iyziJSTag);
  },
};
iyziInit.createTag();
```

This code, creates a whole payment form inside `<div id="iyzipay-checkout-form"></div>`.

I can't just have it as normal react code, because it is coming from the api of payment gateway provider. This script needs to run and directly add those elements to the dom.

**Here is the problem:**

If I paste this code into the console of the browser, it runs, adds script tags to head of document, which then creates my form inside of the div. And I can see the form.

However, if I put this code inside my react app, it runs, adds the script tags to head of the document, then nothing happens. The form is not created, my div with id of "iyzipay-checkout-form" is empty.

Why? I'm losing my mind, can't figure this out for 2 days.

Should mention this too: If I create a standalone index.html, put this code in script tag on head of the document, and then just add a div with id of "iyzipay-checkout-form", this does create the form on that html page. So that code only doesn't work inside react.

You can test this on React Playground: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-4ht85

On the page you see, you won't see the form even tho there's the code to create it, but if you open the console of the playground, and paste the same "that code" i've given on top of this question, the form will appear. You can right click inspect too, to see the head tag and the stuff created inside it.

Comment: Plase add your code directly in your question. Why paste it in an external site, and add a link?

Comment: thought it is simply too long, alright i'm editing it now to post directly.

Comment: That's alright, I took the liberty to make a runnable snippet with it :)

Comment: Now the problem (so to speak) is, the code you provided works. I understand that when you put this code in your React app, it does nothing, but I don't have a React app to test that (I'm not even a React developer) so I'm not sure how to reproduce your issue. Any error in the console?

Comment: Presumably `<div id="iyzipay-checkout-form"></div>` is part of a component which is being re-rendered by React.  I don't see that element here or any reference to its `id` here, so it sounds like this 3rd party tool is taking care of that.  If that's the case, and if this 3rd party has no React support (nor is there any other 3rd party which has added such support that you can find) then you may need to create your own React wrapper component that re-initializes this functionality when it renders, which may involve some digging into this 3rd party functionality.

Comment: No there aren't any errors in the console. At least no errors related to this problem,

Comment: My bad on not adding a playground, i just prepared one and added it to the question. So you can directly see the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue is that the script that's injected by `iyziInit.createTag();` expects the `iyziInit` variable to be defined in the global scope (attached to window).

Here's an example below that works and shows the form.

```
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function MyComp() {
  const [, setCalled] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCalled(called => {
      if (!called) {
        window.iyziInit = {
          currency: "TRY",
          token: "23bfa27a-172a-493d-b42f-8b091589eaa0",
          price: 2.4,
          locale: "tr",
          baseUrl: "https://sandbox-api.iyzipay.com",
          merchantGatewayBaseUrl: "https://sandbox-merchantgw.iyzipay.com",
          registerCardEnabled: true,
          bkmEnabled: true,
          bankTransferEnabled: false,
          bankTransferRedirectUrl: "https://localhost:3000/callback",
          bankTransferCustomUIProps: {},
          campaignEnabled: false,
          creditCardEnabled: true,
          bankTransferAccounts: [],
          userCards: [],
          fundEnabled: true,
          memberCheckoutOtpData: {},
          force3Ds: false,
          isSandbox: true,
          storeNewCardEnabled: true,
          paymentWithNewCardEnabled: true,
          enabledApmTypes: ["SOFORT", "IDEAL", "QIWI", "GIROPAY"],
          payWithIyzicoUsed: false,
          payWithIyzicoEnabled: true,
          payWithIyzicoCustomUI: {},
          buyerName: "John",
          buyerSurname: "Doe",
          merchantInfo: "",
          cancelUrl: "",
          buyerProtectionEnabled: false,
          hide3DS: false,
          gsmNumber: "",
          email: "email@email.com",
          checkConsumerDetail: {},
          subscriptionPaymentEnabled: false,
          ucsEnabled: false,
          fingerprintEnabled: false,
          payWithIyzicoFirstTab: false,
          metadata: {},
          createTag: function() {
            var iyziJSTag = document.createElement("script");
            iyziJSTag.setAttribute(
              "src",
              "https://sandbox-static.iyzipay.com/checkoutform/v2/bundle.js?v=1634688058781"
            );
            document.head.appendChild(iyziJSTag);
          }
        };
        window.iyziInit.createTag();
        return true;
      }
    });

    return () => delete window.iyziInit;
  }, []);

  return <></>;
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
      <MyComp />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You probably want to clean that up a bit, this is from a clean react-app project. You should also probably rewrite the MyComp component as a hook, but this should give you a good starting point.